# Django rest serializer don't work with many to many relationship

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an personal project based on a simple kanban, the model task have a relationship with model board.

When I try renderize it, I get the items: title and slug, but, the relationship with model board is missing, can someone help me with this error please, what I doing wrong?

OBS: I know, here in stackoverflow have many posts with the same subject, but unfortunately I did not find the solution :/

here is my model code:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    BACKLOG = 'Backlog'
    PROCESS = 'In progress'
    QA = 'QA'
    COMPLETE = 'Complete'
    _status = ((BACKLOG, 'Backlog'), (PROCESS, 'In progress'), (QA, 'QA'),
           (COMPLETE, 'Complete'))

    LOW = 'Low'
    NORMAL = 'Normal'
    HIGH = 'High'
    _priority = ((LOW, 'Low'), (NORMAL, 'Normal'), (HIGH, 'High'))
    status = models.CharField(_('Status'), max_length=20, choices=_status,
                          default=BACKLOG,
                          help_text='Selecione o status da task')
    priority = models.CharField(_('Priority'), max_length=20, choices=_priority,
                            default=NORMAL,
                            help_text='Selecione a prioridade da task')
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Board'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Boards'
        ordering = ['priority',]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.description, self.priority)

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Tittle'), max_length=100,
                         help_text='Titulo da task')
    slug = models.SlugField(db_index=True)
    board = models.ManyToManyField(Board)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Task'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tasks'
        ordering = ['title',]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.title)
```

in my serializers file I have the following code:

```
class BoardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Board
        fields = ('description', 'priority', 'status')

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    boards = BoardSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title', 'slug', 'boards')
```

And in my views I have this code:

```
class TaskList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

Here is the items rendered:

```
[
  {
    "title": "create the login page",
    "slug": "create-the-login-page"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    board = models.ManyToManyField(Board)
```

change to

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    boards = models.ManyToManyField(Board)
```

then run:

```
 python manage.py makemigrations
 python manage.py migrate
```

in terminal.
As field name in models must be the same with field name in serializer

Comment: Thank you very much @Ykh, I just changed the variable name in my serializers file, now it work :D